# How to rename 'Sink: Writer' in Apache Flink

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, terraform, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to set custom names for my Sink: Writer jobs to avoid confusion due to having multiple Sink jobs. Could someone please help with this?
I am using Java and Terraform.

[image: Source and Sink jobs]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to provide custom names for operators like the Sink Writer that are created implicitly.